# Where is the ISR macro's definition located for AVR microcontrollers?

Tags: c, microcontroller, interrupt, avr, isr

I've looked through both `<avr/io.h>`, and `<avr/iom328p.h>` for a macro which defines the ISR macro, as well as the datasheet for the ATmega328P and I have yet to find anything. All I can find is external sources saying that you make an interrupt service routine by writing

```c
ISR (/*<ISR-vector>*/)
{
    /* ISR code here */
}
```

but I haven't found its source/definition anywhere.

Comment: Maybe in `avr/interrupt.h`? https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html. I've never used any of this old stuff myself, so I'll refrain from posting an answer.

Comment: @lundin what’s confusing is that `avr/interrupt.h` isn’t included in `avr/io.h` or `avr/iom328p.h`, so where does it get included to allow me to use the `ISR` macro?

Comment: Easiest way is to text search the whole lib.

Answer (score 1):

The macro is defined in `avr/interrupt.h`, which you can view for example [here](https://github.com/dinuxbg/avr-libc/blob/master/include/avr/interrupt.h#L125) (github mirror, not an official source). In case you were looking for it to understand how it works i also recommend you read about `interrupt` and `signal` function attributes [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Function-Attributes.html), because all that the `ISR` macro does is define a function with a specific attribute and name.